# Passing values from Controller to Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel and I'm trying to pass a value from one controller to another controller.. In this case.. I want to pass the order_id generated in Order Controller to /pizza/create in Pizza Controller..

this is my code in OrderController

```
public function store()
        {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $order= new Order;
            $order->user()->associate($user);
            $order->status = 'unconfirmed';
            $order->save();


            return Redirect::to('/pizza/create')
                ->with('order', $order->order_id);  
        }
```

this is my code in /pizza/create in PizzaController

```
public function create()
    {   

        $id = Session::get('order');
        $order = Order::find($id);

        return View::make('pizza.create')
            ->with('order', $order);

    }
```

this somehow works.. but the value (order_id) disappears when i change views/routes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass a value from controller to controller use session, when you are using redirect and with method it is creating session, when you are using view and with method it is creating variable which you can use in view to display that value.

this create a session

```
 return Redirect::to('/pizza/create')
        ->with('order', $order->order_id);
```

this statement create a variable which you can use in view

```
return View::make('pizza.create')
       ->with('order', $order);
```

above variable you can use in blade or view file

```
{{ $order }}
```

so in create method you need to create a session keep variable alive and available in other controllers

```
public function create()
    {   

        $id = Session::get('order');
        $order = Order::find($id);

        Session::put('order',$id);

        return View::make('pizza.create')
            ->with('order', $order);

    }
```

Comment: thank you @umefarooq. i'm gonna try this one to see if it works :)

Comment: it still doesn't work.. the order is passed to view pizza.create, but when I try to get the $order->order_id to pizza.store.. it returns no value..

Comment: are you getting order in session in pizza.create method.

Comment: yes.. i get order in pizza.create.. then i passed it to the view pizza.create.. then afterwards.. i am trying to pass the order_id again to pizza.store.. so i can store the created pizza..

Comment: ok if you are using pass order id to view and view has form than create one hidden input field and put order id there <input type="hidden" name="order" value="{{ $order }}" /> once you submit the form you will get order id also. hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thank you @umerfarooq. it solved the problem.. but there is one down side though.. the session value disappears when i refresh the page.. or whenever i go back from another page

Comment: redirect with session is flash session, session::put() make it available to you controllers, please check config/session.php session driver is file check storage/framework/session directory has permission, you can change session driver to database